# C++ Memory Address Allocation

Tags: c++, memory

Apologies i got frustrated and posted question through mobile without proper details

Consider the following C++ code:

```
 int arr[2];
    arr[0] = 10;
    arr[1] = 20;
   // cout << &arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
       cout << &arr + i << "\t\t"<<endl;
    }

    cout << sizeof (arr);
```

cout in for loop prints following

> 0x7ffeefbff580         0x7ffeefbff588

which is 8 bytes farther than the first element

My question is why it is 8 bytes further and not 4 bytes if on my machine sizeof(int) is 4?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @R Sahu this question is not about coding rather it is about a concept that is why i have not provided any code

Comment: Which compiler, toolset, operating system are you using?

Comment: What makes you think that `sizeof(arr)` is 2?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i am using VS 2010

Comment: `why do i get the address of arr[1] which is 8 bytes` Are you measuring pointer's size? Your question is very confusing. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @FaisalKhan, it'll be so much easier to figure out where the misunderstanding is with a [mcve].

Comment: @duskwuff that is because the length of arr is 2 so when i run sizeof(arr) on my machine i get 2

Comment: @FaisalKhan No, that's not what `sizeof` means.

Comment: @FaisalKhan ...and that's not what `sizeof(arr)` would return in this case.

Comment: @FaisalKhan it's **extremely** unlikely that `sizeof(arr)` returns `2`. Show us the code.

Comment: @FaisalKhan `&arr` you are taking a reference to `arr` which of size `8`. And so you "move" in steps of size `8`. Did you mean `&arr[0]`?

Comment: @freakish Yes my confusion is why &arr[1] is 8 bytes further rather than 4 bytes? array is of type int and int is 4 bytes on my machine so what is the reason that system has allocated it 4*2 bytes? and i assume if array size was 4 then difference of &arr[1] would be 4 * 4 = 16? Why is that? why not just 4 bytes when 4 bytes can hold the int value why allocate it 8 bytes in my case?

Comment: @FaisalKhan This `&arr` returns a pointer to `int[2]` which is a structure of size `8`. **It does not return a pointer to int**. And so `&arr + 1` moves 8 bytes forward. `&arr[1]` **is not** 8 bytes futher. Because what you should do is do `&arr[0]` instead of `&arr` because `&arr[0]` **is a pointer to int** while `&arr` **is not**. They point to the same place but they are of different size, hence pointer arithmetic works differently.

Comment: @FaisalKhan Your expression `&arr + i` is not what you think it is. Using `(void*)(arr + i)` or `&arr[i]` would be more correct.

Comment: @freakish many thanks for your guidance. I just did &arr[1] and i got exactly as i was expecting it to be (4 bytes memory). This is what i was confused about. I am kind of newbie learning about pointers and c++ thanks again :)

Comment: @FaisalKhan When you do `&arr + i` what you are getting is  `(&arr) + i`, when you really want `(arr + i)` (no ampersand needed in this case).

Comment: @Blastfurnace Many thanks for your comment. Yes i got it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that you gave us the code we can answer your question.

So the confusing piece is this: `&arr + i`. This does not do what you think it does. Remember that `&` takes precedence over `+`. And so you take address of `arr` and move it forward `i` times.

Pointer arithmetic works in such a way that `&x + 1` moves the pointer forward by `size(x)`. So in your case what is `size(arr)`? It is 8 because it is 2-element array of integers (I'm assuming ints are of size 4). And so `&arr + 1` actually moves the pointer 8 bytes forward. The exact thing you experience. You don't ask for next int, you ask for next **array**. I encourage you to play around, for example define `arr` as `int[3]` (which is of size 12) and see how the pointer moves 12 bytes forward.

So first solution is to do `arr + i` without `&`. We can apply pointer arithmetic to an array in which case it decays to a pointer type `int*`. Now since `int` is of size 4 then `arr + 1` points correctly to a memory segment 4 bytes forward.

But what I suggest is to stay away from pointer arithmetic and do `&arr[i]` instead. This does the same thing but IMO is less error prone, less confusing and tells us more about the intent.

Comment: really thanks for your time. This was really helpful. Would you be kind enough to guide me to further resources about memory allocation explained in details?

Comment: @FaisalKhan All we've talked about is a pointer arithmetic and taking references. We haven't touched memory allocation at all. The C++ memory model (and everything else) is a complicated beast. I suppose you can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list